# Trouble comprehending expression

Tags: python, data-structures, hashtable

I was doing a leetcode problem and while reviewing a solution I was quite dumbfounded by a certain line in the solution. The leetcode problem in particular is https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-subarrays-with-sum/

The solution:

```
class Solution:
    def numSubarraysWithSum(self, A: List[int], S: int) -> int:

        res = 0
        sm = 0
        sums = collections.defaultdict(int)

        for a in A:
            sm += a
            res += sums[sm - S] + (sm == S)
            sums[sm] += 1
        return res
```

I understand everything that is going on besides this line:

```
   res += sums[sm - S] + (sm == S)
```

I have never seen a conditional in an addition operation before.

Comment: `==` yields a Boolean, which happens to behave like 1 or 0…

Comment: Try `print(0 + (sm == S))` to see what happens?

Comment: Show us *exactly* what you don't understand from when you traced the intermediate expressions in this code. "Explain this code block to me" is out of scope for Stack Overflow: deconstruct the compound expressions and tell us what you don't understand about one or two of those operations.
That is a Boolean comparison, *not* a conditional flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional expressions evaluate to booleans, which in Python are just subtypes of `int`.  `False` is 0, `True` is 1, so adding `sm == S` is the same as adding 1 if `sm` equals `S` or adding 0 otherwise.

Comment: I had a feeling that it worked it like that, thank you for the clarification :D

Comment: Nitpick: it’s a *comparison*, not a “conditional expression”.